# Android | How to keep orientation unlocked even after changing orientation programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a video player where user can change orientation manually also by rotating the device and by pressing a button click.
When i am clicking the button, orientation changes to landscape but now the orientation gets locked and user cannot move back to portrait just by rotating the device
I have tried this :-

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

and this :-

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

but none of it seems to work.
So, how can i keep the orientation unlocked at all times plus user can switch orientation with a button click keeping the orientation unlocked ?

Comment: let's say that my device is in portrait mode, held vertically, i click on the button and the orientation changes to landscape (programmatically) if you want the rotation to be "unlocked" it should revert to portrait right away because the sensor would say "portrait", the landscape mode was forced. am i missing something?

Comment: You could try activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR); but what is the point of the button if sensor will immediately change orientation back? Button only makes sense if you want to set orientation different to sensor orientation. Maybe press the button a second time to unlock and revert to sensor?

Comment: If you see youtube, even if i change orientation to landscape on button click, and device is in orientation mode, the device does not rotate back

Comment: oh i see, now it makes sense

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: the only solution that come to my mind would set the landscape orientation as you did and then register to SensorManager so that you can detect the next orientation change by yourself and then restore sensor orientation

Comment: Can you give the code for sensor ? How to detect current location with sensor ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this,after changing your desire condition

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Answer (score 2):

After I changing the orientation using a button, I changed the orientation to unspecified within a handler to assure that the orientation has been changed. Here is my code:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // make screen orientation unspecified (sensor change it 
            //according to user action)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
        }
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:screenOrientation="portrait"> in the application section.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".App"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to change one activity's orientation to 180 when opening it and then let the user rotate back to portrait and lock it.

I just added these lines inside onCreate:

```
requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT
requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED
```

The activity is locked in portrait mode in manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.GalleryActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
```